# PostgreSQL Unique Constraint - only one row for two columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints, unique

I have a PostgreeSQL table

```
CREATE TABLE metadado_log_audit (
    source_table varchar NULL,
    name_column varchar NULL,
    is_id_relation bool NULL
);
```

How can I set constraint that only one row have is_id_relation = true and unique source_table

Ex. I can not save source_table = 'user' and is_id_realation = true twice
Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a constraint that enforces unicity of `source_table` where `is_id_relation` is true.

In Postgres, you can use a unique filtered index for this:

```
create unique index metadado_log_audit_idx 
    on metadado_log_audit(source_table) 
    where is_id_relation;
```

**[Demo on fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w6s2SkGE)**:

```
insert into metadado_log_audit (source_table, is_id_relation) values ('user', true);
-- ok
 
insert into metadado_log_audit (source_table, is_id_relation) values ('user', false);
-- ok

insert into metadado_log_audit (source_table, is_id_relation) values ('user', true);
-- ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "metadado_log_audit_idx"
-- DETAIL:  Key (source_table)=(user) already exists.
```

---

Note that Postgres unique indexes do allow duplicate `null` values. In Postgres 15, you can change that behavior with option `nulls not distinct`:

```
create unique index metadado_log_audit_idx 
    on metadado_log_audit(source_table) 
    nulls not distinct
    where is_id_relation;
```

Comment: NULL is another option, how many NULLs (if any) would be allowed?

Comment: @FrankHeikens: by default duplicate null values are allowed - but see my updated answer.